# How to insert ALT character with Edit -> Emoji & Symbols

Tags: keyboard, font, internationalization

I want to insert the Apple's Alt key symbol into a document.

[image]

So I fired up the 'Emoji & Symbols' window and use 'alt' as the search term.

The symbols are not 100% as I expected but close enough. I want to 
use rightmost character in 'Font Variation'

However after trying a few times, the tool will only insert the leftmost symbol `⎇`.

How can get the character that I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the simplest way I can think of is just search for 'option' not alt.

Then it's the only result.

[image]

Alternatively, most of the keyboard 'keys' are in Technical Symbols..

[image]

Comment: I was playing around with the Character Viewer. One interesting question that remains is how to use the characters from among the font variations?

Comment: You have to change your display font for that character. Apple-smart apps like TextEdit will do it automatically if you double-click the variation. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q6jB.png